# Laptop crashes on startup

Tags: windows-7, laptop, acer-aspire

I own a Acer Aspire 5737z; the problem exhibits with a normal Windows login and also in a safe mode login.

What happens is basically, after logging into Windows my laptop has crashed to a black screen originally after 25mins now it's down to 30sec.

Here's what I have tried:

- Opened the laptop cleaned the out the dust. (a small amount of dust
  on the fan and that's it)
- (no sign of any burnt hardware inside the laptop)
- Removed the heatsinks and re-installed them with new thermal paste.
- Tried fresh ram in both ram slots.
- Replaced old hard drive with new SSD
- Clean install of Windows 7.

System specs:

- Acer Aspire 5737z Laptop
- 500GB Samsung 850 EVO
- 2GB DDR3 1066MHz RAM
- Nvidia Geforce 9400mG
- Windows 7

Because I can't install any software inside Windows, is there a program I can run in bios to get a hardware health report?
What could be the cause of the crashes and how might I fix it?

Comment: The extended time makes me think temperature problems first. In your bios, it will tell you the cpu temerature.  No "additional program" is needed for the bios (and for your own reference, you can't install anything extra to a bios), but there should be a section that lists the temps. Report back here which temps you are getting. Also look to see if the temps keep going up as you leave it on for awhile

Comment: Do what Eric F suggests first. If the temps are OK, then boot to a Ubuntu Live CD, or similar, to see if it does the same thing. If it doesn't, run some hardware diagnostics from there.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll give it a go. BTW what is considered an "appropriate" temp?

Comment: Unfortunately the bios doesn't list a CPU temperature.

Comment: As suggested I booted to a Ubuntu live CD. 30 secs after booting into Ubuntu the machine crashes . Any other suggestions or is this machine past recovery?

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't tried it, hit f8 and enter safe mode with command prompt and see if it still dies within 30 seconds.  If not, boot into normal mode and see if it happens then.

If it is fine just sitting there with the blinking command line, then crashes try a recovery disk of some sort.  Kaspersky makes a bootable rescue disk, you can run programs from there.  As someone else suggested, try an Ubuntu disk as well.

I also agree that I'd be concerned about a heat issue try a chill-mat and see if there is any change.  You can buy one at Staples or Best Buy.  If it doesn't work, they are generous with their return times for hardware.